# Difference between linear discriminant analysis and Fisher discriminant analysis

Tags: mathematical-statistics

I've always thought that Fisher discriminant analysis (FDA) was simply a multi-class generalization of linear discriminant analysis (LDA). But a recent paper I was reading states that the methods are fundamentally different, because:

- FDA identifies a low-dimensional linear projection that maximizes the ratio of between-class variance to within-class variance.
- LDA assumes the distribution of each class is multivariate Gaussian, and finds a linear subspace minimizing the probability of misclassification. [1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2205.13565.pdf)

I guess my question is, how are these different? If each class is assumed multivariate Gaussian, isn't the linear subspace that minimizes the probability of misclassification the same as the subspace that maximizes the ratio of within-class to between-class variance? It seems like the same eigenvalue problem has to be solved to find the linear subspace of interest in both methods.

Can anyone shed light on what I'm missing and why these methods are different?

Answer (score 0):

- **Fisher discriminant analysis:** finds a linear discriminant function that maximizes the ratio of between groups variance and within groups variance.

  The result is a *single* discriminant function that can be used to discriminate two or more groups.

  Example: The three groups of iris flowers in Fisher, Ronald A. "The use of multiple measurements in taxonomic problems." Annals of eugenics 7.2 (1936): 179-188.

  - For multiple groups this method can also be performed by finding $n(n-1)/2$ pairwise discriminators.

    Example: classification based on 4 characters for three castes in the United Provinc in section 5 from Rao, C. Radhakrishna. "The utilization of multiple measurements in problems of biological classification." Journal of the Royal Statistical Society. Series B (Methodological) 10.2 (1948): 159-203.
- **Linear discriminant analysis:** finds a set of perpendicular discriminant functions that maximizes the sum (or average) of all pairwise generalized distances between the means of the features of the groups. $D^2 = (\mu_i-\mu_j) \cdot  \Sigma^{-1} \cdot (\mu_i-\mu_j)$

  The results are *multiple* discriminant functions that can be used to create a graphical map of two or more groups sucht that the distances are maximal.

  Example: appendix 5 by Rao, C. Radhakrishna in  Mahalanobis, Prasanta C., et al. "Anthropometric survey of the United Provinces, 1941: a statistical study." Sankhyā: The Indian Journal of Statistics (1949): 89-324.

> I've always thought that Fisher discriminant analysis (FDA) was simply a multi-class generalization of linear discriminant analysis (LDA).

Both are multi class, but LDA can result in more components/functions.

The first of the LDA components coincides with Fisher's linear discriminant. (if pooling and prior class probabilities are matched accordingly)